# Access samba shares before login

Tags: samba, file-sharing

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on an old Compaq C300. I want to use it to share my movies over LAN so that the rest of my family can watch without hi-jacking my PC.

I installed samba and shared the Public folder under the Home folder of my user account. But I can only access this folder from my Win 7 PC when I am logged in. If I log out or restart without logging in then I cannot access the shared folder.

I am used to the Windows service that starts at boot making shared files available over the network before the user has logged in. How can I accomplish this in Ubuntu?

Comment: You can try defining the shares through the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` config file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unshare the Public folder;
2. Open the smb.conf file (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, then run `sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`) and insert these lines at **the end** of the file:

   ```
   [Public]
       path = /home/<username>/Public
       public = yes
       writable = yes   # Only add this line if you want to give them write (create, delete, modify) permissions.
   ```

   Then save and close the editor;
3. Still in terminal run `sudo service samba restart`, or just reboot the computer.